# How to select all images without the first one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've got the following problem. Downloaded one script, and it's loading all images from div's body. I want to add one more image here, which won't be processed by the script.

It's like that in code:

```
<div id="myGallery0" class="spacegallery">
<img src=ADDITIONAL.jpg alt="" atr1="1" />  
<img src=images/bw1.jpg alt="" atr1="1" />
<img src=images/bw2.jpg alt="" atr1="2" />
<img src=images/bw3.jpg alt="" atr1="3" />
</div>
```

So my question is, how to select in jquery all of these images EXCEPT the "ADDITIONAL.jpg" one?

My second question is how to select it in natural JavaScript by using one of the GetElementsBy functions.

Comment: $('img:lt(1)').hide(); to hide first one or $('img:gt(0)') to select all except first one like $('img:gt(0)').css('border','solid 1px red');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Raw JavaScript

The raw JavaScript version uses [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) and [`Element#getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) and then skips the first one:

```
var list, images = [], index;
list = document.getElementById("myGallery0").getElementsByTagName("img");
for (index = 1; index < list.length; ++index) {
    images.push(list[index]);
}
// Use the `images` array
```

Starting the loop with `index = 1` skips the first one (which would be `index = 0`).

Or you can get really tricky, but I'd test it thoroughly on your target browsers:

```
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementById("myGallery0").getElementsByTagName("img"),
    1);
```

That works because according to the specification, [`Array.prototype.slice`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.10) **must** allow the object it's working with to be something other than an array, as long as it supports the operations listed in the specification for the `slice` method. And the `NodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName` does, so we can call `slice` passing it the `NodeList` as the `this` value and telling it we want a slice starting with index 1. But note that the spec also quite clearly says *"...Whether the `slice` function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent."* and `NodeList` is a host-provided object, hence the recommendation to test thoroughly in your target environments.

#### jQuery

In jQuery, there are lots of ways to do it. My favorite would probably be [the one Rui pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10348030/157247), using [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
var images = $("#myGallery0 img").slice(1);
```

Comment: Can I use this slice method as a .find() attribute?

Comment: @user1353905: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: @pawel: Yes (assuming you have something in front of that). `find` returns a jQuery object. `slice` is a jQuery method, so it works on all jQuery objects.

Comment: Hey I've got one more issue - my script was calling this:  $('img', elelement).each(function(nr){...}                        and if I repladce $('img, element) by $(('img').slice(1),element) - it's empty (when i'm using 'img' it shows me all 4 images). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @pawel: I strongly recommend you take a step back and take an hour to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com). It will save you a lot of time in the long run. What you want there is `$('img', element).slice(1)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a combination of the `:not()` pseudo and the `:first` selector:

```
var $images = $('#myGallery0').find('img:not(:first)');
```

I guess my vanilla js solution alongside HTML5 would look like:

```
var images = document.getElementById('myGallery0').querySelectorAll('img');

images = Array.prototype.filter.call(images, function( node, idx ) {
    return idx > 0;
});
```

---

update:

I'd also agree that in this particular instance, the jQuery `.slice(1)` is more sexy (and also faster), that is

```
var $images = $('#myGallery0 img').slice(1);
```

But this will only work if you're cutting the first item. With those pseudo selectors you could also easily cut away, lets say the second node like using `img:not(:eq(1))`. While this is also possible with `.slice()`, it would get a lot more tricky to do so.

Comment: Thank you for fast and useful response!

Answer (score 4):

Just another option:

```
$('#myGallery0 img').slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`slice` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a part of a result:

```
$('#myGallery0 img').slice(1)
```

The plain Javascript version would be similar, with a trick to convert the element collection into an array:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.getElementById('myGallery0').getElementsByTagName('img')
).slice(1)
```